# ASP.NET MVC remove dynamically created views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model in my ASP.NET MVC app that holds a List of objects. Each of these objects are visualized using EditorTemplate. Using a dropdown I can add dynamically new object to the List on postback. The problem is when I try to remove a specific element from the list.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public List<MyModel> Items { get; set; }

     public MyViewModel()
     {
          this.Items = new List<MyModel>();
     }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } // I bind this to UI using EditorFor html helper
}
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
     myViewModels.Items.Add(new MyModel());  // Simulate initializing the Id and Text properties

     return View(myViewModel);
}
```

Then in Index.cshtml:

```
if (Model.Items != null)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Items);  // EditorTemplate is used here...
}
```

So in my template file, called Item.cshtml I have:

```
@model MVCApp.Models.MyModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)

    <span class="deleteItem" data-item-id="@Model.Id">Delete</span>
</div>
```

Now I don't know how to process the deletion of the specific item when I click on "Delete". My goal is to have the item deleted from the collection in the controller ('Items' list property of the view model). I can delete the div element using jQuery but the property would not be removed from the 'Items' collection and I would like to avoid jQuery to preserve data integrity between server and client side. I tried to call another action in HomeController called Remove(int? id) where the id parameter is the Id property of 'MyModel', but I need to pass 'MyViewModel' object in Remove action in order to access the 'Items' list, remove the element and then redirect to 'Index' action with the changed collection. How can I achieve that? Thanks!

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Where can I click (or do something) to delete an item?

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot, forgot to add it at first place...

Comment: You can create Web API calls and call from JQuery to first to delete the record and then second to update the page.

Comment: You can remove the `if (Model.Items != null)`. If you dont want to use javascript/jquery, then the 'delete' button need to be inside a form that posts to a controller `Delete(int ID)` method that deletes the item in the database and redirects back to the `Index` get method

Comment: You might want to use `<a>` tag instead of `<span>` tag. Just like: `<a href="yourController/yourDeleteAction/@Model.Id">Delete</a>` It should work

Comment: you have to retrieve the specific record from db and then load into object, then delete the object from the db. finally reload your collection

Comment: @Kevin, A 'delete' action should never be a GET (always a POST)

Comment: Guys, I don't use database at all, these dynamic elements are created from partial view. @Kevin - when I use another form that points to Delete(int ID) method, this form is going to be inside the main form that points to Index action and I cannot add multiple dynamic controls.

Comment: Then you will need an additional property in your model (say) `bool IsDeleted` and bind a checkbox to it so when you submit you can check the value and remove the item from the collection.

Comment: Let's say I have this method:

public ActionResult Delete(MyViewModel myViewModel, int id)
{ ......
}

'myViewModel' variable is always null.

Comment: Try it: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = Model.Id })) { <a href="#" onclick="form.submit();">Delete</a> }` A `Delete` action needs an `Id` to find an item. After passing `Id`, on your `Delete` action, you can: `var temp = yourDatabase.yourTable.Where(x => x.Id == Id);`

Comment: @Kevin, I'm not using database, in order to remove the element, I need access to my viewmodel object... I'm wondering how to send my viewmodel through the form and have it as a parameter in Delete method.

Comment: `private List<MyModel> model = new List<MyModel>();` `public ActionResult Index() { model.Add(new MyModel()...) }` `public ActionResult Delete(int id) {var temp =  model.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
model.Remove(temp);}`All of them are in `HomeController`

Comment: You need to define a field which all method can access and modify it.

Comment: Between the two requests this field "model" is reset due to the stateless nature of HTTP protocol and when I get to Delete action the model has default property values...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it using. You can submit form using submit button and pass in the id to remove and then calling controller action and code accordingly.